# Json Nested Object Array to Table

Tags: javascript, json, facebook, object, multidimensional-array

I have a json file, there is an array of objects. In the first object is a 2nd array with +/- 200 objects. Is there a possibility to show the 2nd array in a new table in the last row of the first table?

As seen here, there should be a nested table in the column: "Friends"

http://jsfiddle.net/TqbMC/

The html is:

```
<body onLoad="buildHtmlTable()">
<table id="excelDataTable" border="1">
</table>
</body>
```

The rest of the code is:

```
var myList=[{
"id": "220439",
"name": "Bret Taylor",
"friends": {
  "data": [
     {
        "id": "100003461417780",
        "name": "Pedro Fernandes"
     },
     {
        "id": "100004448132997",
        "name": "Tatiane Rodrigues"
     },
     {
        "id": "100002608573875",
        "name": "Gerson Yoody"
     },
     {
        "id": "100003532942622",
        "name": "Brennen Roup"
     },
     {
        "id": "100003910478450",
        "name": "Maruxita Gomez"
     },
     {
        "id": "100003035179424",
        "name": "Ekta Vaghasia"
     },
     {
        "id": "100003034655176",
        "name": "Nikita Adam"
     },
     {
        "id": "100004269720826",
        "name": "Lukas Ks"
     },
     {
        "id": "100004489472386",
        "name": "Hong Finozaza"
     },
     {
        "id": "1436623789",
        "name": "Dianita M Ct"
     },
     {
        "id": "100004324535652",
        "name": "Ana Paula"
     },
     {
        "id": "100004433135086",
        "name": "Caroline Geovannini"
     },
     {
        "id": "100004081013147",
        "name": "Ryan Bispo Silva"
     },
     {
        "id": "1697844686",
        "name": "Louann Hyatt Clark"
     },
     {
        "id": "100003283377051",
        "name": "Ysabel Salazar"
     },
     {
        "id": "100003398360349",
        "name": "Ty SoHigh Walker"
     },
     {
        "id": "100001201489463",
        "name": "Dicu Andrei D"
     },
     {
        "id": "100001811128458",
        "name": "Cristy Torres Castellanos"
     },
     {
        "id": "1693121601",
        "name": "Jasim Amit"
     },
     {
        "id": "100001966217366",
        "name": "Candy Chhokar"
     },
     {
        "id": "100004096284395",
        "name": "Stefania Bilska"
     },
     {
        "id": "100004084157244",
        "name": "Papah Noval"
     },
     {
        "id": "1791202672",
        "name": "Bianca Agostina Gherardini"
     },
     {
        "id": "100000825894241",
        "name": "Usman Faiz"
     },
     {
        "id": "100002424916440",
        "name": "Muhammad Tajminur Rahman"
     }
  ],
  "paging": {
     "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/99394368305/likes?limit=25&after=MTAwMDAyNDI0OTE2NDQw"
  }
  }
  }];

// Builds the HTML Table out of myList json data from Ivy restful service.
 function buildHtmlTable() {
 var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(myList);

 for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++) {
     var row$ = $('<tr/>');
     for (var colIndex = 0 ; colIndex < columns.length ; colIndex++) {
         var cellValue = myList[i][columns[colIndex]];

         if (cellValue == null) { cellValue = ""; }

         row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
     }
     $("#excelDataTable").append(row$);
 }
 }

 // Adds a header row to the table and returns the set of columns.
 // Need to do union of keys from all records as some records may not contain
 // all records
 function addAllColumnHeaders(myList)
 {

   var columnSet = [];
   var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');

 for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++) {
     var rowHash = myList[i];
     for (var key in rowHash) {
         if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) == -1){
             columnSet.push(key);
             headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));
         }
     }
 }
 $("#excelDataTable").append(headerTr$);

 return columnSet;
 }
```

(the data comes from the facebook graph api)

Comment: you can access inner data in this way: myList[0].friends.data[i].id and myList[0].friends.data[i].name, just iterate until  myList[0].friends.data.length is reached and build whatever structure you want - for example create table row for each friend with two td - one for id and one for name

Comment: Thanks!! this helped me a lot!
http://jsfiddle.net/6v8Ew/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can access inner data in this way: myList[0].friends.data[i].id and myList[0].friends.data[i].name, just iterate until myList[0].friends.data.length is reached and build whatever structure you want - for example create table row for each friend with two td - one for id and one for name –  [magyar1984](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2698899/magyar1984)

http://jsfiddle.net/6v8Ew/1/

```
for (var x = 0 ; x < myList[0].friends.data.length ; x++){

                $line.append( $( "<td></td>" ).html( myList[0].friends.data[x].id ) );
}
```